# Numerical integration strategy for oscillatory integrand

Tags: numerical-integration

What is the best procedure for calculating the following kind of oscillatory integrals?

```
NIntegrate[f[t] BesselJ[n, t] Sin[t x - n Pi/2], {t, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {-1 < x < 1, n > 0}]
```

where f[t] is bounded at infinity

For instance, for f[t] = 1 there exists a closed form solution for validation of the numerical results, namely

```
W[n_, x_] := -(Sin[n ArcCos[x]]/Sqrt[1 - x^2])
```

I tried three different approaches:

```
W1[n_, x_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
   BesselJ[n, ArcTanh[t]] /(1 - t^2)
     Sin[ArcTanh[t] x - n Pi/2], {t, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];

W2[n_, x_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[ BesselJ[n, a] Sin[a x - n Pi/2], {a, 0, Infinity},
    Method -> {"ExtrapolatingOscillatory", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];

W3[n_, x_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[BesselJ[n, a] Sin[a x - n Pi/2], {a, 0, Infinity}, 
   Method -> {"DoubleExponentialOscillatory", 
     "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0} ];
```

Here the numerical results:

```
In[1]:= Quiet[Timing[W1[3, .3]]]

Out[1]= {0.109375, 0.376386}

In[2]:= Quiet[Timing[W2[3, .3]]]

Out[2]= {2.07813, 0.662773}

In[3]:= Quiet[Timing[W3[3, .3]]]

Out[3]= {0.015625, 1.14447*10^123}
```

The exact solution is

```
In[4]:= W[3, .3]

Out[4]= 0.64
```

How can I improve the numerical solution?
Thanks

Comment: How about `NIntegrate[ BesselJ[3, t] Sin[0.3 t - 3 Pi/2], {t, 0, Infinity}]` which performs `0.64`in 12.2?

Comment: You may wish to review "Advanced Numerical Integrations" under NIntegrate help which covers oscillatory integrands.

Comment: I get errors that suggest I shouldn't trust some of the results. You should probably address them in your work and in the question.

Comment: I would say that `"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0` is actually preventing `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` and `"DoubleExponentialOscillatory"` from doing a better job than they are here.

Comment: Of course, if I remove "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0" then it calculates the integral analytically and provides the correct result. See user64494 post.